# Docker/Rancher : No healthy hosts meet the resource constraints

Tags: ubuntu, docker, containers, rancher

Im creating two hosts but when im triying to create a container (ubuntu for example) in each one i got this error message :

[image]

```
Docker version 17.03.2-ce, build f5ec1e2
Rancher version : v1.6.13
```

My hosts :

[image]

Comment: I'd love to help, as I got a lot of rancher experience... But to be honest, we stopped using rancher on all our servers (and all our clients' servers) because of many random crashes and misleading error messages. This is one of those misleading ones. Sometimes a restart helped. Sometimes a complete rancher reinstall did. Sometimes a special flag (can't remember which one) helped. So in the end we abandoned rancher and wrote our own stack scripts. Don't think rancher will be stable enough to be worthy of my or my colleagues' time any time soon...

Comment: is that any alternative ? open source solution ?

Comment: When you are creating ubuntu containers, are you adding any kind of scheduling rules? Without that information it's kind of hard to debug.

@AlexKarshin as with any software there would be some bugs which get fixed when reported. I personally have fixed a lot of networking issues and helped make the product better. Please feel free to file github issues and we would be happy to address all of your concerns.